Otel Java Agent Instrumentation
I have maven Java Spring Application. I'm trying to implement otel java agent instrumentation to set span with custom attributes.
I have mentioned the below JVM args in Tomcat configuration
-javaagent:C:\opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
-Dotel.javaagent.extensions=C:\Users\Thiru\.m2\repository\com\se\monitoring\agent-extension\24.03.00-SNAPSHOT\agent-extension-24.03.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
-Dotel.service.name=se.main
-Dotel.traces.exporter=zipkin
-Dotel.logs.exporter=none
-Dotel.metrics.exporter=none
-Dotel.instrumentation.spring-scheduling.enabled=false
-Dotel.javaagent.debug=true

I have another library trace-core-1.22.4.jar this library contains code to populate the ThreadLocal attributes. It is populated with attributes successfully (ThreadLocalTraceManager.java).
In agent-extension-24.03.00-SNAPSHOT.jar i have added otel agent instrumentation code, which contains 2 files
HttpUrlConnectionAgentExtensionModule.java
HttpUrlConnectionAgentExtension.java

Inside agent-extension-24.03.00-SNAPSHOT.jar i want to set Span attributes from ThreadLocalTraceManager.
I have added as dependency to trace-core and created fat jar, the library is present in the jar, but i'm getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
[otel.javaagent 2024-06-07 16:24:36:318 +0530] [http-nio-8090-exec-1_7dd5fcd9-eb3d-4994-8144-c73ad0c360f3-TargetGroupB] DEBUG io.opentelemetry.javaagent.bootstrap.ExceptionLogger - Failed to handle exception in instrumentation for sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ssse/trace/impl/ThreadLocalTraceManager
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:174)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1302)
    

Anyone guide me how to achieve this?

can you open an issue in https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation and include a small repro? that would be the best way that we can help you from the OpenTelemetry Java Instrumentation project side

solved it using extending SpanProcessor and able to set custom attributes.
